# How I would call JSON data using information I don't have (like variables)

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

I'm writing a discord bot but currently I have ran into something that I have never worked with before and don't know how I would put it

I have tried using variable names but that doesn't work because it thinks i'm looking at it inside the JSON file

Node.JS Code:

```
if (command == 'untrust') {
    if (msg.author.id == '341761972142080002') {
        const tUser = msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first()) || msg.guild.members.get(args[0])
        for(i = 0; i < trust.length; i++) {
            if (trust[tUser.user["username"]].id === tUser.user.id) {
                let splitter = trust[tUser.user["username"]].id
                console.log(splitter)
                } else {
                  console.log('not it');
               }
            }
         }
        fs.writeFile('./trusted.json', trust, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
{"discordaccountname1":{"id":"354405790645354499"}, "discordaccountname2":{"id":"354405790645354499"}}
```

I expected the result to dig into the JSON file and use the users information in a variable name to find the path in the JSON but it can not do that.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) like so: `trust[tUser.user.id]` (you should always store IDs instead of usernames).

**Update:**
For your purpose, your JSON file should be set up like so:

```
{
  '189855563893571595': ['1234', '5678']
}
```

This is much more readable and easier to use. `trust[message.author.id]` would simply be an array of the users they trust. Then you could use your `for` loop to go through it. Again, always store IDs (static) instead of usernames (dynamic).

Comment: I'm unsure if you know what I am trying to achieve because if I want to gain the id of someone stored in the JSON file by going through their username stored in the JSON file my code will have to have a constant username but I am trying to put the username of the person that was mentioned in the command to be the subject. For example: trust.PERSONSNAME["id"]

Comment: The above code does that, just with the ID of the user.

Comment: Make sure that what you're looking for exists. I'd also recommend using a `for` loop instead.

Comment: I hatched this up
`
                        for(i = 0; i < trust.length; i++) {
                            if (trust[tUser.user["username"]].id === tUser.id) {
                                let splitter = trust[tUser.user["username"]].id.split(",");
                                console.log(splitter)
`
And it outputs this:
`
{ accouname1: { id: '354405790645354499' } }
null
`
I don't know why all of a sudden it becomes null

Comment: Perhaps it is the file saving that messes up because my code is correct as tested with console.log(trust[tUser.user["username"]].id); and it returns the id i'm looking for

Comment: Could I maybe pop it?

Comment: How exactly is your JSON file set up? And am I correct to assume you're storing a user's trusted people?

Comment: My JSON is fine I believe seeing as it logged correctly to my terminal. And yeah I am storing a list of usernames containing an id in a JSON file that the bot reads from and allows them if they can use the bot

Comment: If my JSON were to be formatted it would read like this:
`{  
    "discordaccountname1":{  
        "id":"354405790645354499"
    },
    "discordaccountname2":{  
        "id":"354405790645354499"
    }
}`

Comment: No need to have an object containing just an ID. Just use an array. Also, what exactly is null? `tUser` is actually a GuildMember with your current code so you should use `tUser.user.id` as a GuildMember doesn't have an ID property.

Comment: Changing the JSON structure would mean I will have to change lots of code :/ As far as im aware my code works it is just when it is being saved